How to change the title of the "Create & create another" button in Filament
I'm trying to change the button title on the modal that opens up. Modalsubmitactionlabel only works for one of the buttons but the "Create & create another" button doesn't seem to have any methods for it?

Here's my code:
<?php

namespace App\Filament\Resources\CarResource\Pages;

use App\Filament\Resources\CarResource;
use Filament\Actions;
use Filament\Resources\Pages\ManageRecords;

class ManageCars extends ManageRecords
{
    protected static string $resource = CarResource::class;

    protected function getHeaderActions(): array
    {
        return [
            Actions\CreateAction::make()
                ->mutateFormDataUsing(function(array $data) {
                    $data['car_id'] = filament()->auth()->user()->car_id;

                    return $data;
                }),
        ];
    }
}

I've tried
 ->modalSubmitActionLabel('Add')->modalButtonCreateAnother('Add & Add Another')

But no luck.

I figured it out. You have to create an extra footer action and then use it to change the label of the button. Crazy!!
->extraModalFooterActions(fn (Actions\CreateAction $action): array => [
    $action->makeModalSubmitAction('createAnother', arguments: ['another' => true])
        ->label('Save and add another'),
]),

Ref: https://filamentphp.com/docs/3.x/actions/modals#adding-an-extra-modal-action-button-to-the-footer

It's very easy. In your create record file from the Pages folder, you can implement the getCreateAnotherFormAction function. For example:
protected function getCreateAnotherFormAction(): Action
{
     return parent::getCreateAnotherFormAction()
         ->label('Your text');
}

